# How to make file name as folder name in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have Files in Source side as

`ABCD_120320221200.csv`
`FAG_IQ11_12052022.csv`
`FAZ_OP10_210320221300.csv`

I need to make `ABCD`, `FAG_IQ11`, `FAZ_OP10` as Folder names in ADLS and Files should move inside the respective folders.

I have used @split(item.name,'_')
but only ABCD folder got created.

How can I create 3 folders?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I have used @split(item().name,'_') but only ABCD folder got created.

`@split(item().name,'_')` will only splits the string into multiple words and we cannot pick our folder name from the array of words.

To achieve the above requirement, I did like below.

These are my sample source csv files.

[image]

First use Get Meta data activity to get the source folder ChildItems array and give it to the ForEach activity.

Inside ForEach use a set variable activity to get the Folder name. Use below dynamic content for it.

```
@substring(item().name,0,lastIndexOf(item().name,'_'))
```

[image]

The above dynamic content first finds the last occurance of `_` and give that index as required string length to `substring()` function.

Then use copy activity.

In source use wild card path and `@item().name`.

[image]

For sink **create two dataset parameters, one for file name and one for folder name and use those in file path of dataset**.

[image]

In copy activity sink give the variable to the folder name parameter and `@item().name` to the file name parameter.

[image]

**Execute this and files will be copied to the respective folders.**

[image]

[image]

[image]